# Decrease space between normal text and the footnote

Tags: spacing, header-footer

I use approximately this code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=1.8cm,top=0.8in,bottom=1.in]{geometry}

\fancypagestyle{standard_intro}{%

  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \fancyhead[LE]{}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\scriptsize\textbf{\RUNTITLE}\\\ Introduction}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\scriptsize\textbf{\RUNTITLE}\\\ Introduction}
        \fancyhead[LO]{}    
% \vspace{-1cm}
  \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\footnotesize $-\;$\thepage $\;-$ }
  \singlespacing
}
```

For my taste the spacing between the text and footnote, which is the page number is too large. How can I decrease it? The vspace at the position I indicated did not work.
I hope you can already work with this less than minimal example.

Thx a lot
Paul

Comment: OTOH, if you actually wanted to change the space above a footnote, you would adjust \footnotesep (length).

Answer (score 3):

This is not *the* footnote, but the *footer* Its spacing w.r.t. text is set by the value of the`\footskip` length, and it defaults to 30pt. Just add one key to `geometry`, like this:

```
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=1.8cm,top=0.8in,bottom=1.in, footskip=20pt]{geometry}
```

if you want to set it to 20 pt

Comment: +1: footnote vs. footer :)